# Android In app unmanaged server verification

Tags: android, transactions, in-app-billing

I want to use for the first time the in app purchase in my application. I use an unmanaged item (it's a virtual monney) and I want to verify the transaction with my public key on a server side.

To do this, I used [AndroidBillingLibrary](https://github.com/robotmedia/AndroidBillingLibrary).  and I set a "signatureValidator" to be called on "validate(String signedData, String signature)". This is works, I received the signedData and the signature and I return "false" to say "it's not a correct purchase". I launched my WS (async) with this and if it's ok I call "BillingService.confirmNotifications()", else I don't do anything.

But my problem : if the server doesn't validate the transaction, I don't call "confirmNotification" but the transaction is still validate and the custumer have to paid. How can I do to wait the server response and cancel (or just not confirmed) the transaction it's not OK ?

Thanks !

Edit, I add some code :

```
private void requestPurchase(String purchaseId) {
    mPurchaseId = purchaseId;
    // request my purchase
    BillingController.requestPurchase(this, mPurchaseId, false, null);
}

// Receipt the answer of my purchase
@Override
public boolean validate(String signedData, String signature) {
    // when a purchased need to be checked
    mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, null, getString(R.string.loading), true, false);
    RequestHelper.getInstance().executeRequest(getRequestCheckReceipt(signedData, signature);
    return false;
}


// Receipt the answer of my WS
@Override
public void onRequestReceived(Request request) {
    if (mProgressDialog != null) {
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            mProgressDialog = null;
    }
    if(request.isOk()) {
        BillingService.confirmNotifications(this, new String[] { mPurchaseId };);
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, with the new API (v3) now I changed my object to "managed" and I consume it when the server tell me the key is correct.

Comment: I think you need to add some server side code too.

Comment: I don't think, the server side is really simple : only check the signed data and return true or false.